# Providing advice for courses

Tags: discussion

Now and then we receive questions on course advice. Let's analyze the phenomenon:

1. **It's not constructive**. Virtually the number of courses is high, which makes it a list question. For now our site is small so this might not be a problem... yet.
2. **It might chase away the experts**. I think these questions while they currently don't have many answers are kind of tarnishing our site. Experts don't like these questions and I agree with it. They are not Linguistics questions, just recommendation questions.

So what do the community thinks?

Comment: I've only seen one such question.  Do such questions occur with sufficient frequency to be worth addressing?

Answer (score 1):

I think we should explicitly forbid them in the FAQ. Generally they are considered poor questions, not challenging at all and not useful for others in general.

My opinion on why have been expressed on the Question.

Comment: I agree that those questions might not be interesting or challenging, but they're relevant for those who ask them. It's about sharing knowledge and helping users who are interested in learning/discussing linguistic issues. We don't really know the specific circumstances that motivate someone to look for help here, and perhaps it's a bit unfair to close that door. I think you're right, and the nature of this site excludes such questions, but I wonder if there is a way to help those users. What kind of alternatives can we give them to find those answers that cannnot be provided here?

Comment: @KleinePrins Any question is relevant for the OP. The matter is if it's widely applicable and here I remind you that we have a close reason for this (Too Localized). But regardless of that, I think they still are a bit poor. Not really the kind of site I'd like this to be. Do we want a recommendation site or a site that provides knowledge? The alternative is Chat. We have an unused chat room where people can ask for help, advice on any matter. Why not use that instead of trying to post a question at all costs? If the question doesn't work, it doesn't.

Comment: Sure, I agree. Then I ask you if there is a way to suggest people that they should go to the chat before posting a question that is likely to be closed.

Comment: @KleinePrins Automatic? Uhm, not that I remember... But the FAQ is pretty clear on such questions. All we can do is reminding people using comments, but more than that...

Comment: OK. I understand better now. Thanks!

Comment: @KleinePrins You're welcome! Any doubt, just ask me... Or any proposal, just propose. :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't find "Add comment",so I just post it here.
Add a "Soft question"tag,just like mathSE,I think that will work.